# I got stuck with my first code in C programing language, I cannot make an excutable file?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I used to compile and run *C codes* in windows OS using **code block** program, at the mean time, I am using LINUX OS (Ubuntu 14.10 LTS)

I've created a simple program (hello ,world!). This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Its name is `demo.c`

When I try to make an executable file `demo` via:

> gcc demo.c -o demo

I cannot get a green executable  file!!!!!!!!!!

When I try

> ./demo

I get

> bash: ./demo: Permission denied

for more informations, I have posted the outputs of some command in the following link
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259982/error-while-compiling-my-first-program-in-c-language?noredirect=1#comment451370_259982

Comment: What permissions are on the file?

Comment: @MartinJames really, i don't know ,what can i type to know??

Comment: @robin.koch I've tried it before but nothing!!

Comment: if you still get permission denied, you are running the terminal with a user different from the user that compiled the program. adjust the owner or use chmod a+x ./demo to grant execution permission to everyone on your system.

Comment: Post the output of `file ./demo` after you've successfully compiled `demo.c`.

Comment: but i used to get a green executable file after typing `gcc demo.c -o demo` but now i get a normal file. When i try to execute this file i get `bash: ./dem: Permission denied` when i type  `chmod a+x ./demo` i got nothing (i should get `Hello! This is a test prgoram.`

Comment: Don ot add tags for unrelated languages! C++ and C are **different** languages!

Comment: Don't post only links! Paste text instead.

Comment: Please type `pwd` in your console to see where are you trying to compile that source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output of the various commands in your other question, it looks like you are using a file system that does not respect or store file permissions (is this an NTFS partition used by Windows and you configured the machine for dual boot?).

Try working in a directory that is on a native Linux file system, for example your home directory.

Comment: More likely he is using an USB stick with VFAT which is possibly mounted `noexec` for security reasons.

Comment: That is another possibility, and something to watch out for. In this case however the output from df and mount shows that they are on a /dev/sda partition mounted using FUSE.

Comment: Hmm, We are not supposed to follow links in a question. A question has to be self-contained. Good point, but why does that exclude `noexec`?

Comment: The mount table doesn't show noexec flag for the fs in question

Answer (score 0):

> bash: ./demo: Permission denied

Just ensure your executable is created and then Change permission by doing

```
chmod u+x <executable name>
```

This will give the `x` - "execute" permission for the "owner" - `u` of the file, which should be enough to execute the file, provided it is an executable.

Comment: I should get `Hello! This is a test prgoram.` but nothing